# Cannot delete a remote branch created unintentionally

Tags: git, version-control

```
$ git branch -a
* SocialAct
  master
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/master
  remotes/origin/SocialAct
  remotes/origin/social
```

I want to delete the remote branch "remotes/origin/social", and applied folloing command:

```
$ git branch -d -r origin/social
Deleted remote branch origin/social (was 26f6f61).
```

But I have no idea how to bring these changes remotely so that the branches are deleted from origin and everyone can see the changes. I tried git push but that does not work

Any help.

Answer (score 45):

I had this error (from above):

> Thanks. Actually I noticed this
>   solution and tried earlier. But this
>   gives following error... $ git push
>   origin :heads/socail Enter passphrase
>   for key '/h/.ssh/id_rsa': error:
>   unable to push to unqualified
>   destination: heads/socail The
>   destination refspec neither matches an
>   existing ref on the remote nor begins
>   with refs/, and we are unable to guess
>   a prefix based on the source ref.
>   error: failed to push some refs to
>   'git@xxxxxx.git' – Himel May 24 '10 at
>   9:37

It seemed to have gotten confused about whether or not I had actually deleted it remotely. I worked around it like so:

```
git push origin HEAD:branch_to_delete

git push origin :branch_to_delete
```

That worked for me. Using: *git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0*.

Comment: Looks like the branch was already deleted.  git pull won't remove remotely deleted branches, you have to use prune:  git remote prune origin -  http://stay-calm.blogspot.com/2009/02/git-prune-to-remove-old-remote-tracking.html

Comment: The comment above me should be the highest rated answer here. Of course Nathan's method works, but it hides the true mistake here.

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned by [@Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/423384/josh) in a comment on [Nathan McDaniel's Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4949821/526741), this is likely due to the branch no longer existing in the remote repository. This causes `git branch -a` to still show the branch under `origin` (or whatever you happened to name this particular remote), but deleting the branch on the remote repository is impossible because it no longer exists on the remote. This could have been caused by deleting the branch on the remote from another computer (on top of the fact that `git pull` and `git fetch` do not remove references to remote branches that have been deleted from the remote repository).

## The fix

Simply remove all remote-tracking branches that have already been removed from the remote repository with `git remote prune`:

```
git remote prune REMOTENAME
```

For example, if your remote's name is `origin` (likely), the above command would look like:

```
git remote prune origin
```

From the documentation provided with `git`:

> **`git remote prune [-n | --dry-run] <name>`**
>
> Deletes all stale remote-tracking branches under `<name>`. These stale branches have already been removed from the remote repository referenced by `<name>`, but are still locally available in "remotes/".
>
> With `--dry-run` option, report what branches will be pruned, but do not actually prune them.

Answer (score 7):

`git push origin :social`
But you need to delete locally as well, before or after.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I noticed this solution and tried earlier. But this gives following error...

$ git push origin :heads/socail
Enter passphrase for key '/h/.ssh/id_rsa':
error: unable to push to unqualified destination: heads/socail
The destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the source ref.
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@xxxxxx.git'

Comment: I have deleted locally first, with command:

$ git branch -d -r origin/social

or, did I do it wrong?

Comment: It doesn't matter that you delete locally or not, did u notice your last example has a typo socail/social ?

Comment: Right, there was a typo, actually I wrote it here. but in actual console I applied it right.

Comment: Last time I had to do that it was exactly like that, in any case, the error message looks like the branch is not there any more, have you tried a to clone the repo and see if the branch is still there?

Comment: I shall try that. Good hint and thanks. Actually after applying the command, I have been verifying the end result in the repository URL (web) and the branch is still there. So I could not be sure that I could delete it.

Comment: At this point I'd check if the web interface is properly updated, or still showing cached content. Try to do a commit and see if the web reflects it.

Comment: If this isn't working, it's also possible that the remote repo is set up to not allow remote branch deletions. All the repos I administer are configured that way (because deleting a branch allows you to get around non-fast-forward update restrictions :-P ). In such a case the only way to delete the branch is to go to the remote repository and do it there.

Answer (score 3):

The below command will delete the remote tracking branch but not the branch which exists on remote

```
$ git branch -d -r origin/social
Deleted remote branch origin/social (was 26f6f61).
```

To delete remote branch:

```
git push origin  :social
```

This will automatically delete the remote tracking branch i.e remotes/origin/social.

Answer (score -3):

Deleting remote branches is described in detail over [here](http://github.com/guides/remove-a-remote-branch).