# Unable to delete or prune a remote branch with no commits

Tags: git

I accidentally created a branch and pushed it to the origin. I created it out of another branch, but didn't commit any changes, so it should be "identical" to the original branch.

I want to remove the branch, so I first removed it locally with:

```
git branch -d <branch_name>
```

and then I wanted to remove from the remote location with:

```
git push origin :<branch_name>
```

but this gave me the error:

> error: unable to push to unqualified destination:  The
>   destination refspec neither matches an existing ref on the remote nor
>   begins with refs/, and we are unable to guess a prefix based on the
>   source ref. fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

I found information about this error on another thread in StackOverflow ([Cannot delete a remote branch created unintentionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895906/cannot-delete-a-remote-branch-created-unintentionally)) and on other sites ([git: prune to remove old remote tracking branches](http://stay-calm.blogspot.com/2009/02/git-prune-to-remove-old-remote-tracking.html)), but the solution they propose:

```
git remote prune origin
```

does not work for me. The prunning command exits correctly, but **I still see the branch** when I `git branch -r` or `git branch -a`.

I have also tried `git remote update` and `git fetch` but that didn't change anything.

How can I remove this branch from the list of branches?

Comment: `git remote prune` will only clean up your local refs, once the branch is removed from the remote repository.  Does `git ls-remote origin` show the branch still being there?  If so, and `git push origin :<branch_name>` isn't removing it, I'd try the fully-qualified path name: `git push origin :refs/heads/<branch-name>`.  You should see the fully qualified name in the output of `git ls-remote`.  Just copy and paste that.

Comment: Thanks @jszakmeister! See my comment on poke's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `git fetch --prune origin`.

Otherwise you could manually remove the branch from your local repository and see if it comes back on `git fetch` (in which case it wasn’t removed on the remote):

```
git branch -d -r origin/branch
```

Comment: Thanks. The only command that worked was `git branch -d -r origin/branch`. I guess my question now is: Why? and how is this command different from everything I tried in my original post?

Comment: Did the branch come back on `git fetch`? Or is it gone for good now?

Comment: Actually, after `git fetch` it is back.. :/

Comment: Then there is your answer. Apparently deleting the branch on the remote repository failed (or it was added back by someone else), as such, all your prune-methods didn’t remove your local link to it. Try removing the remote branch again with `git push origin :branch` (make sure you specify the exact name) and if that does not work, it might be the remote repository that has a problem with it (or maybe disallows it?).